# Choosing a random function

Tags: jquery, if-statement, random, alert

```
else {
    alert('That was wrong!')
    alert('Too bad, try again!')
}
```

I want the else to pick a random alert, for example if I have the answer wrong it pick a random alert and if I have the answer wrong again I want it to pick another random alert. How do I do this in jquery? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an array of messages. Then get a random value from the array which can be used to display the message.

```js
var myArray = ['That was wrong!', 'Too bad, try again!', 'Lets try once again!'];
var randStr = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
alert(randStr)
```